# How to make ng-multiselect-dropdown a required field?

Tags: angular, dropdown, multiple-select

i need to make my multiple select drop down required. any attribute that would make the dropdown required?

here is what i have :

```
 <ng-multiselect-dropdown [placeholder]="'Select multiple mask.'"
                                                 [data]="dropdownList"
                                                 [(ngModel)]="selectedItems"
                                                 [settings]="dropdownSettings"
                                                 (onSelect)="onItemSelect($event)"
                                                 (onSelectAll)="onSelectAll($event)"
                                                 [ngModelOptions]="{standalone: true}"
                                                 id="multipleSelectId"
                                                 >
                        </ng-multiselect-dropdown>
```

when i click on the submit button it submits. i have tried adding ng-required and required attribute. none of them works.

Comment: Check this answer for reference if it might help, https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25133058/how-can-i-validate-angular-multi-select

Answer (score 1):

Make a hidden input element with the same model as the multi-select

```html
<div ng-dropdown-multiselect options="ctrl.list" selected-model="ctrl.item"></div>
<input type="hidden" ng-model="ctrl.item[0]" ng-required="true">
```